# Displaying chess pieces with unicode in eclipse using java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, chess

Im just trying to display some unicode chess symbols in eclipse using java, however it just prints out the random rectangles, and unless chess pieces have taken a radical change in style lately- i dont think its what i want. Help is much appreciated!

my code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class ChessSymbols {
public static void main (String [ ] args)throws
UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String unicodeMessage =
                        "\u2654 " + // white king
                        "\u2655 " + // white queen
                        "\u2656 " + // white rook
                        "\u2657 " + // white bishop
                        "\u2658 " + // white knight
                        "\u2659 " + // white pawn
                        "\n" +
                        "\u265A " + // black king
                        "\u265B " + // black queen
                        "\u265C " + // black rook
                        "\u265D " + // black bishop
                        "\u265E " + // black knight
                        "\u265F " + // black pawn
                        "\n" ;
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream (System.out, true , "UTF8" );
        out.println(unicodeMessage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the Eclipse run configuration to run your code, you need to set the character encoding of the console dialog.  You can do this (I'm checking Indigo, I am not certain about earlier versions) by bringing up Run Configurations, selecting the Java run command in question, clicking on the Common tab, and on the right there is a way to select the character encoding of the console (which much be UTF8 for your program to work).

I found this out by typing "encoding for console" in the search help dialog.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, click Run -> Run Config. -> Common Tab -> Encoding  -> Other : UTF-8  : this fixed it here

I'm running Version: Helios Service Release 2, Build id: 20110218-091  On Windows 7.

You may like to try using command line too.

It's an issue with Eclipse's console. Please see this article, you need to edit eclipse.ini - http://paranoid-engineering.blogspot.com/2008/05/getting-unicode-output-in-eclipse.html

Comment: Windows, what a royal mess... +1 for the link.

Comment: I meant what transpired from the content on the link you provided.

Comment: @l10i - Yes I know :) , sorry about that one it was messier than using the menus.

Comment: @Adel thanks dude, tried this but it didnt solve the propblem :(

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it does work correctly on my Linux.
Tried it from the bare shell and from Eclipse.
This is not a Java problem but a console charset problem. You have to look into the encoding your console accepts and make sure it is UTF8. Eclipse shouldn't factor in that.

Comment: @l10i So how do i check the encoding my console accepts? I changed the eclipse.ini config file by adding "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8". I thought that would allow me to use unicode in the console. Thanks.

Comment: What you set is the encoding of files. This is not the encoding we are dealing with. We want the "display" encoding of the console. What is your operating system, just for starters?

Comment: @l10i Windows 64-bit. I tried the above already and it hasnt worked. I also tried doing it by removing the edit i made in the .ini and just did it via run config, as well as doing it with both. Didnt make a difference. Any idea?

Comment: Let us analyse the problem step by step. Does your Java class produce correct characters when run from the bare Windows shell? At least then we can identify whether Eclipse has a part on this.

Comment: @l10i k, just tried it, not working in the shell. Does that mean its a windows problem then? Thanks for this btw.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not conclusive in that sense. I suggest you fix your Windows console as a first step, then check if Eclipse works too. I cannot help you further since I do not have access to a Windows PC.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the font does not have the glyphs you need.
Try changing the font of the console.