# convert 2D array into chess board

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make android chess game. I already have the engine working with a text based UI like this:

```
bR bN bB bQ bK bB bN bR 8
 bp bp bp bp bp bp bp bp 7
    ##    ##    ##    ## 6
 ##    ##    ##    ##    5
    ##    ##    ##    ## 4
 ##    ##    ##    ##    3
 wp wp wp wp wp wp wp wp 2
 wR wN wB wQ wK wB wN wR 1
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
White's move:
```

I would like to convert this 2D array into graphical UI. All the moves work correctly and print out the result or the error if the move was successful or not. I know it would be something like a gridview kind of thing. I am not looking for code but a sort of algorithm or a process where I can convert this 2D array in a view for example: e2 e4 moving the pawn will result in this

```
 bR bN bB bQ bK bB bN bR 8
 bp bp bp bp bp bp bp bp 7
    ##    ##    ##    ## 6
 ##    ##    ##    ##    5
    ##    ## wp ##    ## 4
 ##    ##    ##    ##    3
 wp wp wp wp    wp wp wp 2
 wR wN wB wQ wK wB wN wR 1
  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
Black's move:
```

I would like to redraw the board after the move was successful using the data in the 2D array. The board data seen above is stored in the data array.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a coordinate transformation system to turn chess notation (e2) into array positions(assuming origin at top left, [4][6])

Comment: I like the ASCII art you've made :)

Comment: Do you want to allow users actually **make moves** via GUI or just **display** them?

Comment: I need the UI the engine is written in java, but the end UI has to been in android so I was thinking just call the program send the two coordinates and getting the 2D array back and again redraw the board itself...

Comment: Make moves like select the piece to move and its destination and I will pass on the coordinates to my engine and get the 2D array back and redraw the board back for the next move..

Comment: @jrdnsingh89: I think there's some misunderstanding about the real question here. You're submitting a small form (textfield source, textfield destination, submit) which updates the array on the java engine. The client will be redirected to the new board / get a rendered version of the board?
Where's the question here? How to redirect the user / rerender the board?

Comment: I don't see a question in this post, nor any real specification of what you expect an answer to contain. Worse still, there seems to be no effort on your part to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered going only part way?

Make a new UTF8 printstream:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF8");
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7665120/823393) to a list of the UTF8 codes for each chess piece.

You may need a font that covers these codes - I found Monospaced 13 works fine for me.

Here's an example from some experimental code I wrote a while back - looks better in Monospaced:

```
    ♜|♞|♝|♚|♛|♝|♞|♜
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    ♟|♟|♟|♟|♟|♟|♟| 
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    +|*| | | | | | 
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    +| |*|+|*| | |♟
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    +| | |♙| | |*|+
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    +|*| | | | | | 
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    ♙|♙|♙| |♙|♙|♙|♙
    —+—+—+—+—+—+—+—
    ♖|♘|♗|♔|♕|♗|♘|♖
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question, you're just providing another GUI.

Comment: I would like it to be graphical like a normal chess game where I can select a piece and a destination spot and get the coordinates and call my engine to get the 2D data and redraw it..

Comment: @Aquillo - it is going `only part way` as stated.

Comment: @jrdnsingh89 - Your call. Good luck.

Comment: So? You're not providing the OP with any way to redraw his board, which he asked for.

Comment: @Aquillo - A simple loop will draw the board. I expect OP has that already judging by the samples in the question. I am merely pointing out that a UTF8 stream can be used to print UTF8 chess pieces if a good font is selected. By all means flag my answer if you feel it is inappropriate in some way.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon It's not inappropriate in any way, don't get me wrong. I think you're providing OP with another great way of displaying his chessboard. Though, OP came here with a question which is not answered in your 'answer'.