# Print chess symbols using UnicodeBlock?

Tags: java, unicode, java-12

With `jdk12`, came Chess symbols ([source](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/12-relnote-issues-5211422.html)):

> Unicode 11.0.0 introduced the following new features that are now included in JDK 12
>
> [...] 4 blocks for the following existing scripts:
>
> - Georgian Extended
> - Mayan Numerals
> - ndic Siyaq Numbers
> - Chess Symbols

With that in mind, I tried to print those characters with the following code, to test the functionality and use those later in a little chess game:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.CHESS_SYMBOLS;
for (int i = 0; i < 1114112; i++) {
    char unicode = (char) i;
    if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(unicode) == block) {
        System.out.println(unicode);
    }
}
```

However, it is not printing anything. The code works if I replace `CHESS_SYMBOLS` with, for instance, `ARABIC`. I have java 12.0.1.

Question: Why isn't the above code printing anything ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665120/displaying-chess-pieces-with-unicode-in-eclipse-using-java

Comment: @StephenC I'm using Intellij, if I try `System.out.println("♔");` it does print the symbol, so I believe it is strictly code-related

Comment: @SteveSmith It is not printing rectangles, it is printing nothing at all. Also I'd like to use `UniblockCode` to do the printing, or at least understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: You are only checking the first 65536 characters there are 1,114,112 Unicode characters.

Comment: @JGNI I edited the code, still not printing though. I also tried `Character.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Have you set the charset to UTF-8?

Comment: @SteveSmith If `System.out.println("♔");` does work then it must not be a charset issue, or maybe something has to be specified in code ?

Comment: Maybe the Windows charset doesn't contain all the unicode characters? https://coderanch.com/t/538165/java/Displaying-UniCode-characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some chess symbol characters exist in the Miscellaneous Symbols block, but you are specifically checking for 16-bit `char` values in a different block.  The Chess Symbols block contains *zero* characters with 16-bit values;  it starts at U+1FA00, and ends at U+1FA6F.

By casting to `char`, you are trimming all values above U+FFFF to their lowest 16 bits;  for example, if `i` is [0x1fa60](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1fa60/), casting it to a `char` will make it 0xfa60, which prevents your block check from succeeding.

To make your code work, you need to stop assuming that all codepoints are 16-bit values.  You can do that by changing this:

```
char unicode = (char) i;
```

to this:

```
int unicode = i;
```

Comment: Of course, when changing `char unicode = (char) i;` to `int unicode = i;`, there is no need for two distinct variables at all.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `Character.UnicodeBlock` doesn't have methods to tell what is the beginning and ending value for code points within the block. In Unicode 11 the chess symbols block runs from U+1FA00 to U+1FA6D.

Java uses UTF-16 and [surrogate pairs to represent characters over U+10000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903008/what-is-a-surrogate-pair-in-java). In this case code point U+1FA00 will be represented as two `char` values: U+D83E (high surrogate) and U+DE60 (low surrogate).

You should use `Character.toChars()` to correctly print the code point which is always an `int`:

```
Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.CHESS_SYMBOLS;
for (int i = 0; i < 1114112; i++) {
    if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(i).equals(block)) {
        System.out.println(Character.toChars(i));
    }
}
```